# Using transactions inside double for loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, transactions

How can I create transactions for queries ? for every new account I'm creating 210 new records into the database. I need transactions because the 210 queries taking time and I use the `mysql_insert_id()` to get the last inserted id. here the code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bla bla....";

$result =  mysql_query($sql);
$lastid = mysql_insert_id();

if($result)
{
    for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++)
    {
        for($j=1; $j<=30; $j++)
        {
            $query_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$i.' days 1 hours'));
            $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `e-heal`.`scr` (`sc_id`, `d_id`, `hour_id`, `date`, `a`) VALUES (NULL, '$lastid', '$j', '$query_day', '0');";
            mysql_query($sql_insert);
         }
    }     
}
```

Comment: "I need transactions because" --- it doesn't explain **why** you need transactions. You can do what you need without them as well

Comment: If 2 or more users clicks the register button the same time ???
for one user takes 3-4 seconds add the records into the database..

Comment: "If 2 or more users clicks the register button the same time" -- so? "for one user takes 3-4 seconds add the records into the database" -- so? Transactions **DO NOT** improve performance

Comment: @Romain Hippeau: how? help with "what"? ;-)

Comment: I'm not doing this for **performance!!** to ensure the last inserted it for the records

Comment: @MoonFox: `mysql_insert_id()` has nothing to do with transactions and *always* returns the correct latest autoinctement value (even if 100 millions of users pressed the button simultaneously)

Comment: @MoonFox: really. That's why it's always a good idea to ask original question, since your solution might base on a wrong assumption

Answer (score 1):

You don't need transactions here - `mysql_insert_id()` **GUARANTEES** to return the latest autoincrement value from the current session.